# How to ask for one argument out of two using GetOptions?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a CLI script in perl that accepts multiple CLI args. I'm parsing these arguments using the `GetOptions` function. I have 2 options `--foo` and `--bar` one of which exactly one has to be present with the corresponding value passed to it.

Is there a way to handle this directly in GetOptions? or do I have to manually write the check for this?

I'm using the `Getopt::Long` module.

**EDIT:** When I said:

> I have 2 options `--foo` and `--bar` one of which exactly one has to be present with the corresponding value passed to it.

I meant to say that these should be CLI arguments to be used as either:

```
$ perl my-cli-script.pl --foo somevalue
$ #Or
$ perl my-cli-script.pl --bar someothervalue
```

but not

```
$ perl my-cli-script.pl --foo somevalue --bar someothervalue
$ #or
$ perl my-cli-script.pl
```

Comment: I'm not aware of Getopt::Long having this functionality. Not even Getopt::Long::Descriptive seems to offer it. Please add the name of the module you are using to your question, not only the function name.

Comment: @tinita I'm using the `Getopt::Long` module.

Comment: @tinita, I think [`Getopt::Long::Descriptive`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long::Descriptive)'s `one_of` thingy is what the OP is after.

Comment: It would be nice to see some code. If something must be present, then it's not an option and should be a command-line argument.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I've updated my question.

Comment: Maybe make them both optional and then in your code see which ones are set and act accordingly?

Comment: That's the last resort. I was thinking if something is already there so that I dont have to rewrite it. Seems like `one_of` is the one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find that this is a perfect time to be aware of the little-used `xor` (exclusive or) operator.

```
GetOptions(
   "foo=s" => \my $foo,
   "bar=s" => \my $bar,
) or die "Bad options";

unless ( defined $foo xor defined $bar ) {
    die "You must specify either --foo or --bar, but not both";
}
```

Comment: The `or` operator ist missing in the 4th line. Thus, the appropriate line should be:  

    ) or die "Bad options";

Comment: Thank you, HRitter. Oops :) (and fixed)

Answer (score 7):

Just check afterwards.

```
GetOptions(
   "help|h|?" => \&help,
   "foo=s"    => \$opt_foo,
   "bar=s"    => \$opt_bar,
)
   or usage();

defined($opt_foo) || defined($opt_bar) )
   or usage("Must specify --foo or --bar");

!( defined($opt_foo) && defined($opt_bar) )
   or usage("Can't specify both --foo and --bar");

@ARGV == 0
   or usage("Too many arguments");
```

---

Sample `usage`:

```
sub usage {
   if ( my ($msg) = @_ ) {
      chomp($msg);
      warn("$msg\n");
   }

   my $prog = basename($0);
   warn("Try `$prog --help' for more information.\n");
   exit(1);
}
```